# CS50 P9: expected status code 400, but got 200

Tags: python, flask

I am stuck with the CS50 Finance exercise because I am getting this error when I run check50:

[image]

[image]

I have already reviewed some threads about similar issues like this:

https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/29176/pset7-c50-finance-check50-error-expected-status-code-200-but-got-400

Please find below my codes (I would appreciate any help):

app.py

```
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")

# Make sure API key is set
if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):
    raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


###################################################################
#
# index: display info about the shares of the user
#
###################################################################


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    # Select each type of share owned by the user and it's amount
    #
    portfolio = db.execute("SELECT shares, symbol FROM stocks WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])

    # Update prices and total for each type of share
    #
    total_cash = 0
    for i in portfolio:
        symbol = i["symbol"]
        shares = i["shares"]
        stock = lookup(symbol)
        total = shares * stock["price"]
        total_cash = total_cash + total
        db.execute("UPDATE stocks SET price = ?, total = ? WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", usd(stock["price"]), usd(total), session["user_id"], symbol)

    # Get user's cash
    #
    updated_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])

    # Get user´s total
    #
    total_cash = total_cash + updated_cash[0]["cash"]

    # Print info in index homepage
    #
    updated_portfolio = db.execute("SELECT * from stocks WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])

    return render_template("index.html", stocks = updated_portfolio, cash = usd(updated_cash[0]["cash"]), total = usd(total_cash) )


###################################################################
#
# buy: enables a user to buy stocks
#
###################################################################


@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""

    # method POST
    #
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Check for valid input (stock)
        #
        stock = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
        if not stock:
            return apology("Invalid Symbol")

        # Check for valid input (number of shares)
        #
        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
            if shares < 0:
                return apology("Shares are invalid")
        except:
            return apology("Shares are invalid")

        # Ensure user has enough cash to afford the stock
        #
        # By default each new user has $10,000.00
        #
        money = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        purchase = stock["price"] * float(shares)
        cash = float(money[0]["cash"])

        if not money or cash < purchase:
            return apology("Not enough money")

        # Update cash to reflect purchased stock
        #
        cash = cash - purchase
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", cash, session["user_id"])

        # Update shares that user purchase
        #
        # Table "stocks" was created for saving the shares that user purchase
        # Its structure is:
        #
        # id:       id of user
        # symbol:   symbol of the stock that user own
        # shares:   number of shares that user owns
        # price:    price of one share
        # total:    total amount of shares that user own
        #
        user_shares = db.execute("SELECT shares FROM stocks WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", session["user_id"], stock["symbol"])
        if not user_shares:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO stocks (shares, price, total, symbol, id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", shares, usd(stock["price"]), usd(shares * stock["price"]), stock["symbol"], session["user_id"])
        else:
            shares_total = user_shares[0]["shares"] + shares
            db.execute("UPDATE stocks SET shares = ? WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", shares_total, session["user_id"], stock["symbol"])

        # Redirect user to home page
        #
        return redirect("/")

    # method GET
    #
    # User reaches route by clicking a link or via redirect
    #
    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")


###################################################################
#
# history: display history of all transactions
#
###################################################################


@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():

    """Show history of transactions"""
    my_history = db.execute("SELECT * from history WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
    return render_template("history.html", history = my_history)


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """Log user out"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Redirect user to login form
    return redirect("/")


###################################################################
#
# quote: request a stock quote and shows the result
#
###################################################################


@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""

    # method POST
    #
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Lookup a stock symbol and returns a stock quote
        #
        result = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

        if not result:
            return apology("Symbol was not found")

        # If lookup is succesful then shows the result
        #
        return render_template("quoted.html", stock = result)

    # method GET
    #
    # User reaches route by clicking a link or via redirect
    #
    else:
        return render_template("quote.html")


###################################################################
#
# register: allows a user to register for an account via a form
#
###################################################################


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    # method POST
    #
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        #
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username")

        # Ensure password was submitted
        #
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password")

        # Ensure password was re-submitted
        #
        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("must re-enter password")

        # Ensure both passwords match
        #
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("password does not match")

        # Ensure username does not exist
        #
        if db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username")):
            return apology("username already exist", 200)

        # Insert new user into database
        #
        username = request.form.get("username")
        hash = generate_password_hash("password")
        new_user = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(?, ?)", username, hash)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        #
        session["user_id"] = new_user

        # Redirect user to home page
        #
        return redirect("/")

    # method GET
    #
    # User reaches route by clicking a link or via redirect
    #
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")


###################################################################
#
# sell: enables a user to sell stocks
#
###################################################################


@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():

    """Sell shares of stock"""

    # method POST
    #
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure proper symbol for stock
        #
        stock = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
        if not stock:
            return apology("Invalid Symbol")

        # Ensure proper number of shares
        #
        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
            if shares < 0:
                return apology("Shares are invalid")
        except:
            return apology("Shares are invalid")

        # Get shares
        #
        user_shares = db.execute("SELECT shares FROM stocks WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", session["user_id"], stock["symbol"])

        # Check if there are enough shares to sell
        #
        if not user_shares or int(user_shares[0]["shares"]) < shares:
            return apology("Not enough shares")

        # Update history of transactions
        #
        # Table "history" was created for saving the shares that user sell
        # Its structure is:
        #
        # id:       id of user
        # symbol:   symbol of the stock that user own
        # shares:   number of shares that user owns (negative because they were sold)
        # price:    price of one share
        #
        db.execute("INSERT INTO history (symbol, shares, price, id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", stock["symbol"], -shares, usd(stock["price"]), session["user_id"])

        # Increase user's cash
        #
        purchase = stock["price"] * float(shares)
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ? WHERE id = ?", purchase, session["user_id"])

        # Decrement user's shares
        #
        shares_total = user_shares[0]["shares"] - shares
        if shares_total == 0:
            db.execute("DELETE FROM stocks WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", session["user_id"], stock["symbol"])
        else:
            db.execute("UPDATE stocks SET shares = ? WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", shares_total, session["user_id"], stock["symbol"])

        # return to index (home page)
        #
        return redirect("/")

    # method GET
    #
    # User reaches route by clicking a link or via redirect
    #
    else:
        return render_template("sell.html")
```

register.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action = "/register" method = "post">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <input autocomplete = "off" autofocus class = "form-control" name = "username" placeholder = "Username" type = "text"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <input class = "form-control" name = "password" placeholder = "Password" type = "password"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <input class = "form-control" name = "confirmation" placeholder = "Confirmation" type = "password"/>
        </div>
        <button class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class = "table table-striped" style = "width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Shares</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    {% for stock in stocks %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ stocks.symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ stocks.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ stocks.shares }}</td>
        <td>{{ stocks.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ stocks.total }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      <tr>
        <td>Cash</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ cash }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>{{ total }}</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the register function into the app.py and the error disappears:

```py
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

    if username == "" or len(db.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?', username)) > 0:
        return apology("Invalid Username")

    if password == "" or password != confirmation:
        return apology("Invalid Password")

    # Add new user to users db (includes: username and HASH of password)
    #
    db.execute('INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(?, ?)', username, generate_password_hash(password))

    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)

    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

    return redirect("/")
```